# how to make a html function work multi times?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to make a prank DIV using html+Js . when you move your mouse over a DIV ( onmouseover ) Js script changes the CSS position of that DIV ( TOP and left ) . but it only works one time and stops working . how can I make it work **many** times in a row ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      random1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 0) + 0);
      random2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * (800 - 0) + 0);

      throwDiv = () => {
        document.getElementById("divdiv").style.top = `${random1}px`;
        document.getElementById("divdiv").style.left = `${random2}px`;
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input
      type="button"
      id="divdiv"
      style="
        background-color: red;
        position: relative;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 50px;
        left: 150px;
      "
      onmouseover="throwDiv()"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Add an event listener perhaps? Idk, need more code

Comment: @elemental_01 add random into the function `throwDiv = () => { `

Comment: ^ This, you are only calculating the offsets once. This makes you believe the code isn't "working", but the code just sets the div to the same top and left each time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm not sure of your condition but according to the provided information

when you are just moving css position on mouse hovering over the div you can use CSS only to achive that

```
:hover
```

is a css property you can use and add the position change you want in it.

and there is also you can change it with javascript using **event listener**

[css hover](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/sel_hover.asp)

Comment: It's a good idea, but we are guessing what the OP is trying to do

Comment: How is this even the accepted answer? @elemental_01

Comment: @elemental_01 why is this the accepted answer ?